# Manually clear context reference when activity is destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-activity, garbage-collection, android-context

I have a BaseWebViewClient class that extends WebViewClient. I use it to setup generic stuff I want for all my webviews (like uri schemes and what not) across my different fragments and activities. This class needs a context reference to access some resources. I pass it in the constructor and set it to a member variable and life is good.

The question becomes, how should I handle preventing memory leaks with this context? Can I just make a clearClient() method that sets the mContext variable to null and call that in onDestory() of the frag/activity? Seems like an easy solution just feels like I'm missing something. Does this seem like a good thing to do or is there a better way to handle this without having to remember to call the clearClient method in the activity?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass it the application context.  Or call getApplicationContext on the context passed in.  You can save that without worrying.  There's very few cases where that isn't good enough.

Comment: I've seen this method used before as well. The only thing I worry about using this approach is will it keep the client object from being GC'd until the app is killed?

Comment: No. You have the linkage reversed there. Holding a reference to another object doesn't prevent the holder from being gced, ever.  Only having your reference held elsewhere will.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize it was that way. That makes more sense now! thanks!

Comment: getApplicationContext() may not be suitable for UI operations such as a Dialog